# Hall $\pi$ subgroup of subgroup of $G$ exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ has a Hall-$\pi$ subgroup for a fixed prime set $\pi$.

If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then can we say that $K$ has a Hall-$\pi$ subgroup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G = {\rm PSL}(2,16)$ has a Hall $\{3,5\}$-subgroup (of order $15$), but $A_5 \cong {\rm PSL}(2,4) < G$ and $A_5$ has no such subgroup.

Another example: $K = {\rm PSL}(2,7) \cong {\rm PSL}(3,2)$ has no Hall $\{2,7\}$-subgroup, but $K < G={\rm PSL}(3,8)$, and $G$ does have one.

On the basis of two examples, I will make the wild conjecture that for any finite group $K$ and any set of primes $\pi$, $K$ embeds in a finite group that has a Hall $\pi$-subgroup.

Comment: nice counterexample.

Comment: I think the question of the OP is true if one assumes that $K$ is normal.

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: If $K$ is normal and $H$ is a Hall subgroup of the big group $G$ then $\langle K, H  \rangle = K H$ and $K \cap H \leq H, K$. We have $[K : H \cap K] = [KH : H]$ and $[G:H] = [G:HK][HK:H]$. Thus $[HK: H]$ divides $[G : H]$, i.e. $[K : H \cap K]$ divides $[G:H]$.